# Missing toolbar and cannot resize areas?

Tags: interface

My first problem is the toolbar. My toolbar is hidden and not showing File, Edit etc..

[image]

By mistake I just remove the center image to get the tool bar but the timeline covers my model working area now and it's now re-sizing. When I drag my mouse pointer to that bar where pointer changes to up, down arrows to re-size the window, but when I click and drag pointer to make my working area bigger and timeline smaller than nothing works, the areas are not moving, just split in more and join.

Comment: See http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Interface/Window_system/Arranging_frames. To get your info window back you'll have to drag down on the little shaded corner in the top right, then change the resulting area's type to *info*.

Comment: You might consider one of the free online courses in using Blender. See <http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15355/resources-for-blender/15376#15376>.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To split or join areas, you can either drag on the shaded corner with <kbd>[image: LMB] LMB</kbd>, or you can <kbd>[image: RMB] RMB</kbd> on the edge between areas and select *Split* or *Join*.

Once you have done that, move the mouse over the area you want to replace and you will see an arrow appear which indicates which area will replace which.

To confirm, either release <kbd>[image: LMB] LMB</kbd> (if you were dragging from the corner widget), or click with <kbd>[image: LMB] LMB</kbd> if you use the <kbd>[image: RMB] RMB</kbd> method.

[image]

To resize areas, drag the edge of the area with <kbd>[image: LMB] LMB</kbd>:

[image]

To change an area's type, click the drop down on the far left of the header and select an editor type:

[image]

So, to fix your layout:

1. Change the top 3D view to an info area and resize it so that only the header is visible.
2. Change the timeline to a 3D view

[image]

For more information, see [the wiki](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Interface/Window_system/Arranging_frames).